# Decode/Encode .swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this .swf file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/hrr3c6c188jsgvd/upload.swf

I need to change something in this file, so I have this website http://www.showmycode.com/ decode the file and got those code:

```
if (!hasOwnProperty("_load05626E90")) { 
    _load05626E90 = true; 
    telltarget ("..") { 
        var copyright = function () { 
            telltarget ("..") { 
                geturl("http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+Script+c-Image+Uploader+3.0", "_blank"); 
            } 
        }; 
    } 
} 
else { 
    // unexpected jump 
} 

var author = function () { 
    telltarget ("..") { 
        geturl("http://chiplove.biz", "_blank"); 
    } 
}; 
// unexpected jump 
// unexpected jump 
var uploadItem = function (num) { 
    telltarget ("..") { 
        var item = flash.net.FileReference(list[num]); 
        item.addlistener(listener2); 
        item.upload((((((((((("upload.php?watermark=" + watermark) + "&logo=") + logo) + "&resize=") + resize) + "&server=") + server) + "&q=") + q)+ "&account=") + account)+ "&password=") + password); 
    } 
}; 
        // unexpected jump 
        // unexpected jump 
        var FileChooser = function () { 
            telltarget ("..") { 
                var fileRef = new flash.net.FileReferenceList(); 
                fileRef.addlistener(listener); 
                fileRef.browse(allTypes); 
            } 
        }; 
        // unexpected jump 
        // unexpected jump 
    }; 
    stop();  
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------- //Frame 1 //---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    this.menu = new contextmenu(); 
    this.menu.hidebuiltinitems(); 
    this.menu.customitems.push(new contextmenuitem("PHP Script - c-Image Uploader 3.0", copyright)); 
    this.menu.customitems.push(new contextmenuitem("Powered by chiplove.9xpro", author));  
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------- //Symbol 3 Button //---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    on (press) { 
        var listener = new object(); 
        var listener2 = new object(); 
        var itemnum = 0; 
        var numfiles = 0; 
        delete _global.__resolve; 
        _global.__resolve = _global.__debugResolve; 

        if (list == undefined) { 
            var list = null; 
        } 
        var allTypes = new array(); 
        var imageTypes = new object(); 
        imageTypes.description = "Images (*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.gif; *.png;)"; 
        imageTypes.extension = "*.jpg; *.JPG; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.gif; *.png;"; 
        allTypes.push(imageTypes); 
        listener.onselect = function (fileRefList) { 
            list = fileRefList.fileList; numfiles = list.length; 
            uploadItem(itemnum); 
            }; 
            listener2.onOpen = function (file) { }; 
            listener2.onProgress = function (file, bytesloaded, bytestotal) { 
                flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("loading"); 
            }; 
            listener2.onComplete = function (file) { }; 
            listener2.onUploadCompleteData = function (file, data) { 
                var loadvars = new loadvars(); 
                loadvars.decode(data); 
                flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("displaypic", file.name, loadvars.image); 
                itemnum = itemnum + 1; 
                if (itemnum < numfiles) { 
                    uploadItem(itemnum); 
                } 
                else { 
                    flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("responseStatus", "Done!"); 
                } 
            }; 
            flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallBack("FileChooser", this, FileChooser); 
            flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("clearlist"); 
            FileChooser(); 
        }
```

I think this is Action Script code, so after make some little change I get flash builder to recompile it, however, flash builder show a lot of red underline (syntax error) in my code and can't build those code to .swf file again. I wonder if the code I got from showmycode.com is correct, or is it action script? If the code I got from showmycode.com is not correct, how can I decode, edit, then encode again that "upload.swf" file?

Comment: It sounds like you are reverse engineering something and expecting it to be possible to engineer it back, doesn't work like that... also what you are doing sounds illegal, is it?

Comment: oh, then is it impossible? What I'm doing is not illegal, someone on the internet shared an upload PHP script that include this damn .swf file, I need to change something, so I have to edit it.

Comment: So talk to the author of the SWF and have him change it

Comment: Well, if it is impossible to edit the .swf file, I guess I will have to do as you say.